# How to run a modified java program in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, smb

I have a project in Java which get a file using smb client. When I edit this code and run it again in Eclipse, it is not running my modified code but running the same old one.

Checklist:

1. I saved the file and made sure there are no write errors.
2. Build Automatically is enabled.
3. Run configuration is configured properly.
4. There are no unresolved errors.

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: There is no error message. It running perfectly fine, but it is running the old code, not my new modified code.

Comment: Do you edit the files in a local folder or on a network share?

Comment: I edited the .java files in a local folder using Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

To find out whether Eclipse has really compiled your code, have a look into the `bin/` folder of the project and check the date of the `.class` files in there. You will have to do this outside of Eclipse since it hides the content of this folder by default.

Use "Clean Project" to force a rebuild.

If that looks correct, the next step is to go to the Debug Perspective. Open the Properties Dialog for the process. Eclipse will then show you the classpath that it used to start the process. Make sure the paths are correct.

Comment: Thanks. Turns out, Eclipse has not really compiled my code. What should i do now?

Comment: Use Project Menu -> Clean -> select your project -> OK. That should force a rebuild. Also make sure that the time stamps of your source files aren't in the future.

Comment: I cleaned the project but looks like Eclipse is not able to rebuild it  (There are no files in the bin folder, even after Ctrl+B). I am getting the main class not found error.

Comment: Okay. Open the "Error Log View". Do you see anything which might be related?

Comment: Yes, it could not delete a few folders and a file when cleaning the project. Does that help in identifying the problem?

Comment: Maybe. I'm wondering why you didn't see an error during clean. Which file?

Comment: Are you using a different build system such as Ant or Maven in your project?

Comment: Some process is using the file. Most likely, you still have an old version of the application running. Or you opened that file in a text editor.

Answer (score 0):

Delete bin folder data and clean project. To clean project:
Go on Project-->Clean-->select your project-->clean-->build project
This will solve your problem, if this does not work, please write a Hello world program and check this works or not. If this is also not working, check your Eclipse

Comment: I cleaned the project. It didnt solve the problem. Hello world didnt work either.

Comment: Reinstall your eclipse with latest SDK, make your work space in other drive than the drive contains your operating system files and folders. refer http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#download